# Vue Template not updating after data is changed

Tags: django, templates, vue.js, axios, updating

I am new to Vue, and I have played around with small vue applications, but this is the first project I've done using vue and webpack (vue-cli).

I have a django rest API set up, for which I then use vue to consume the API and display the data. The issue i'm having is when I want to do anything the templates aren't updating. The data is loaded in correctly, but if I try and do a @click event and then a v-show (to toggle displaying an item) it doesn't change the view.

Example,

lets say I have a list of pubs that I consume from the API.

I get them via axios, and store them in the data function in a array called pubs:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'Pubs',
  data () {
    return {
      pubs: [
        {
          pub_id:'',
          name:'',
          address:'',
          showPub: false,
         },
      ]
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.loadPubs();
  },
  methods: {
    loadPubs: function () {
      var vm = this;
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pubs/')
      .then(function (response) {
        vm.pubs = response.data;
        vm.pubs.forEach(function (pub) {
        pub.showPub = true;
      });
      console.log("loaded");
    })
   .catch(function (error) {
     this.pubs = 'An error occured.' + error;
    });
   },
   togglePub: function (pub) {
     pub.showPub = !pub.showPub;
     console.log(pub.showPub);
     console.log(pub);
     return pub;
   },
 }
}
</script>
```

The template could be:

```
<template>
  <div class="pubs">
    <h1>VuePubs</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="pub in pubs">
        <section>
          <h2 @click="togglePub(pub)">{{ pub.name }}</h2>
          <section v-show="pub.showPub">
            <h3>{{ pub.address }}</h3>
            <h3>{{ pub.postcode }}</h3>
            <h3>{{ pub.showPub }}</h3>
          </section>
        </section>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

I can see that the data is changing in the model, thanks to the vue-dev tools, but the template doesn't change. The section doesn't hide and the h3 tags don't update with the new showPub field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you create a repro? It works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/599/

Comment: Thanks for that, but I find that it works when the HTML is separated from the Javascript like in your example, but when using the single file components it doesn't. Could it be because when I import the data it is not being tracked by vue?

Comment: It does seem like vue isn't keeping track of changes when updating the data in your case. But without a repro I can't really figure out why.

Comment: Will it update the DOM if you `Vue.set(vm, "pubs", response.data)` instead of `vm.pubs = response.data` ?